# DataGridView first row editing doesn't work in checkboxcolumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview like in this image:

[image]

I set `ColumnsHeaderVisible` to `False`, and the first column is a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`.

The problem is I can uncheck all the rows with a mouse click, but first row is not changeable.

I cannot check/uncheck the first row of the table.

I want to say again, I can't do this with mouse click.

What is the problem?

Thanks..

Comment: this is `DataGridView.DataSource = DataTable` or `DataGridView.DataSource = BindingSource`?

Comment: DataGridView.DataSource = DataTable

Comment: i updated my answer. please check

Answer (score 0):

After the bounding of the data you should call in the DataBindingComplete Event

```
dataGridView.ClearSelection();
```

[DataBindingComplete Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete.aspx)

**Edit:**

You can iterate through all rows in the DataBindingCompleteEvent

```
private void dataGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
    DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
       dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @namco - what about dataGridView.CurrentCell = null;

Comment: get Gridview properties, navigate to events, double click DataBindingComplete Event and write the edited code above.

Comment: very very sorry, i can it. i want to check/uncheck with mouse, while program is running.... :)))

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellContentClick);
        } 

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value = !(bool)dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value;

            //Or
            //bool IsBool = false;
            //IsBool = bool.TryParse(dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString(), out IsBool);
            //if (IsBool)
            //   dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value = IsBool;
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:** Place the code in `CellClick event`

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                //Find primaykey from dataTable   
                DataRow[] Rows = dataTable.Select("Id = '" + dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString() + "'");
                Rows[0]["CheckBoxes"] = !bool.Parse(Rows[0]["CheckBoxes"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: when i show ColumnHeaders it works very well, but when i hide it it doesnt work. i dont understand what is the problem.....

Comment: why do you want to `ColumnHeaders = false`?, i will try without the ColumnHeaders

Comment: try to remove the  `if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)`